# swiftmailer mail_send.php error 500-Internal-Server-Error (Log: Timed Out)

Tags: php, external, swiftmailer, postfix-mta, dovecot

My System:

- Operating System: Linux VServer
- Webserver: apache2 Mailserver (Using IMAP): Dovecot
- MTA (MailTransportAgent): Postfix + postfix.admin(webapp) to administrate
- my Domain: acegames.de (137.74.140.78)
- TLS-Mail-encryption via port 465 is working

What i want to do:

Execute (Button on website->javascript->ajax->php) php script mail_send.php (+ query) to send mail with swiftmail functions.
Swiftmail should use my postfix SMTP-Server to send the mail.
The swiftmail files are located in **/var/www/html/ts/swiftmailer/**.

**this is http://ts.acegames.de/mail_send.php 
or /var/www/html/ts/mail_send.php:**

```
<?php 
require_once 'swiftmailer/lib/swift_required.php';

$error = $_GET['err']; $time = $_GET['time']; $user = $_GET['user'];

$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('acegames.de', 465);
$transport->setUsername("USER@acegames.de");
$transport->setPassword("PASS");


$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);


$message = Swift_Message::newInstance('Teamspeak Error Report');
$message->setFrom(array('USER@acegames.de' => 'USER'));
$message->setTo(array('report@acegames.de' => 'ts3 report'));
$message->setBody(
'<html>' . 
' <head></head>' . 
' <body>' . 
' <p>Reported Error: ' . $error . '</p>' . 
'  <p>Time: ' . $time . '</p>' . 
'  <p>User: ' . $user . '</p>' . 
' </body>' . 
'</html>', 'text/html' );




// Send the email 
$result = $mailer->send($message); 
?>
```

But what i get is a 500-INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR and the following log:
**/var/log/apache2/error.log:**

```
[:error] [pid 23732] [client 188.174.41.220:49670] PHP Fatal error:   Uncaught exception 'Swift_TransportException' with message 'Connection
to acegames.de:465 Timed Out'  in
/var/www/html/ts/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/AbstractSmtpTransport.php:404\nStack
trace:\n#0 
/var/www/html/ts/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/AbstractSmtpTransport.php(289):
Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport->_getFullResponse(0)\n#1 
/var/www/html/ts/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/AbstractSmtpTransport.php(117):
Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport->_readGreeting()\n#2 
/var/www/html/ts/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Mailer.php(79):
Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport->start()\n#3 
/var/www/html/ts/mail_send.php(36):
Swift_Mailer->send(Object(Swift_Message))\n#4 {main}\n  thrown in 
/var/www/html/ts/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/AbstractSmtpTransport.php
on line 404, referer: https://ts.acegames.de/
```

I dont know what the issue is. Ive searched through every logfile (mail.log,syslog,apache2 logs,...) but i havent found anything related to this error.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is saying that it is unable to connect to the mail server you specified. You need to specify TLS like this:

```
$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('acegames.de', 465, 'tls');
```

Read more here: [Swiftmailer Manual](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/sending.html#encrypted-smtp)

Comment: good idea but that did not fix anything... ive read that if port 465 is set, you dont need to specify tls because it is default for that port. dont know where i read it but even with 'tls' it still gives me a 500-INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR and the exact same log.

Answer (score 0):

You have timeout error, I suspect it is a port problem, check if output port is available or blocked.

I mean maybe some port between your client and the server are blocked by a firewall or security policy, spam policy, etc.

Comment: so witch port do you actually mean. sorry but i dont know the "output port". i cant find any documentarys about a port like you described it.

Comment: So my hoster says that they don't block ports of the server and neither do i.

Comment: only if i type "telnet acegames.de smtp" it sends the message "220 pph-server.de Postfix ESMTP (Debian/GNU)" and actually reacts to the input.

Comment: looks like postfix isnt actually listening on this port(465)... that is pretty confusing

Answer (score 0):

## More Infos requested by @hokusai:

**telnet acegames.de 465**
Trying 137.74.140.78...
Connected to acegames.de.
Escape character is '^]'.
... 
Connection closed by foreign host.

**telnet acegames.de 443**
Trying 137.74.140.78...
Connected to acegames.de.
Escape character is '^]'.
... 
Connection closed by foreign host.

**telnet acegames.de 80**
Trying 137.74.140.78...
Connected to acegames.de.
Escape character is '^]'.
301 Moved Permanently

Moved Permanently

The document has moved here.

Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) Server at acegames.de Port 80
... 
Connection closed by foreign host.

Answer (score 0):

So, if you control the mailserver on acegames.de, please show the contents of the mail.log (/var/log/mail.log). There's something on Port 465, but the connection is being closed immediately.